# how to stop mouse hover function in small window?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

why,even after applying java script function to stop mouse hover in small window
it's not working? and even when i click on menu it's background color changes to black.every thing seems fine still it's not working ??

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Kewaunee</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- bootstarp css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- userdefined css -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

  <!-- jquery file-->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>

  <!-- bootstarp js-->
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>


   <style>
   .navbar{
    background-color: #3366cc;
   }
   </style>

</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="kewaunee.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home<b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">home 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">home2</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Master<b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Add Region</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Add Tax</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Add Milestone</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Add Customer</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
        <li><a href="#">Transaction</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->

        <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" ></span> Login</a></li>
        <!-- modal login form -->

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <form role="form" method="post" action="#">
                    <div class="form-group-sm" class="col-xs-2">
                      <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group-sm" class="col-xs-2">
                      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#">Forgot password</a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--end of login form -->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">    
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <p class="well"><a href="#">Master</a></p>
      <p class="well"><a href="#">Transaction</a></p>
      <p class="well"><a href="#">Report</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-left"> 
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <hr>
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>&#169 Kewaunee 2015</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

myscript.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {
            $('.dropdown').on('mouseover', function(){
        $('.dropdown-toggle', this).next('.dropdown-menu').show();
            }).on('mouseout', function(){
        $('.dropdown-toggle', this).next('.dropdown-menu').hide();
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.dropdown').off('mouseover').off('mouseout');
        }
  $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
        if ($(this).next('.dropdown-menu').is(':visible')) {
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        }
    });
});
```

myscript.css

```
<style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
      background-color: #3366cc;

    }
    .navbar.navbar-inverse{
      position: relative;
      top: 20px;
    }
    .navbar-brand{
      padding-top: 5px;
    }
    .navbar-header
    {
        height:100%;
    }
   .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a
    {
        color: white;
     }
   .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .dropdown>a:hover
   {
    background-color: red;
   } 
   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu
   {
    background-color:#3366cc;
    border: 1px solid blue;
   }
   .dropdown .dropdown-menu a
   {
    color: white;
   }
   .dropdown .dropdown-menu a:hover
   {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
   }


    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
    .row.content 
    {
      height: 500px;
    }

    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 20px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Dropdown menu*/
    .caret-up {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: 4px solid;

    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #3366cc;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .sidenav {
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      .row.content {height:auto;} 
    }

    .modal-body{
        height: 200px;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: what happens when you mouse over on what... what is small window..??

Comment: whenever i mouse hover on the menu button it shows dropdrown menu , but i want that mouse hover option to off whenever we open that on a mobile screen, it should work like a clickable dropdown menu and small window means like mobile screens. @ Rahul

Comment: so try to check device size first on page load and then apply effect using jquery....

Answer (score 0):

To me this seems to work fine, but if you want the effect not only on page refresh maybe you should in addition to $(document).ready() use also $(window).resize()